# ListView.View is null when used in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I would like to build a WPF UserControl that can display data in different layouts, basically table, groupbox and tab control with tabs. I would like the control to be such that it can host itself recursively. For example I would like to display a table with a groupbox in one of its cells and inside the groupbox again a table layout.

To achieve this I've used a TemplateSelector ("GenericLayoutTemplateSelector") as top level element in xaml with different templates. For the table layout I wanted to use the example "Binding a ListView to a Data Matrix" on code project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36462/Binding-a-ListView-to-a-Data-Matrix

The codeproject example works fine, but when I use it in my context it fails. Since the only change I made, was put the xaml inside a datatemplate / template selector I think, the problem might be related to this.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TableTemplate">
    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="SteelBlue">
        <ListView x:Name="TableLayoutListView" tableLayout:ListViewExtension.MatrixSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ListToMatrixConverter}}">                    
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>                           
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=[0]}" Header="Dummy" 
                         CellTemplateSelector="{DynamicResource GenericLayoutTemplateSelector}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

It fails at the point where inside the ListViewExtension.MatrixSource the GridView is retrieved:

```
private static void OnMatrixSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = d as ListView;
    Matrix matrix = e.NewValue as Matrix;
    listView.ItemsSource = matrix;       
    GridView gridView = listView.View as GridView;
    DataTemplateSelector cellTemplateSelector = gridView.Columns.First().CellTemplateSelector;
```

The listView.View is null. I can create the GridView in Code and assign it to the listView.View but then I don't have access to the GenericTemplateSelector which I wanted to use a the CellTemplateSelector for the GridView.

Any ideas why listView.View is null an what I can do about it?

Edit:
SledgeHammer made it obvious, what I'm trying to do is a bad hack, and it failed. The proper way to do it, is to pass the GenericTemplateSelector directly to the attached property, not via a dummy GridView Column.

I'm trying to figure out a way to do this: my idea is to have an attached property with multi-binding.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TableTemplate">
    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="SteelBlue">
        <ListView x:Name="TableLayoutListView">
            <tableLayout:ListViewExtension.MatrixSourceWithTemplateSelector>
                <MultiBinding Converter={StaticResource ListToMatrixConverter}>
                    <Binding Path="this" />
                    <Binding {DynamicResource GenericLayoutTemplateSelector}/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </tableLayout:ListViewExtension.MatrixSourceWithTemplateSelector>
```

However, this is no valid xaml. Any ideas how to get the {DynamicResource GenericLayoutTemplateSelector} into the multibinding?

Comment: Check the return value from `ListToMatrixConverter` by putting a `breakpoint` in `Convert` method of its class. Have you expected return value there at run-time?

Comment: The converter works as expected and returns a Matrix that is not null and contains some rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to guess that the MatrixSource property is getting set BEFORE the View property. They can't all be set at the same time, obviously. Handle the MatrixSource AND the View changes and call a common method and check for null.

Comment: You are right. It is the order of the setters. However, having a common method for MatrixSource changed and View changed does not fit in the concept of the attached MatrixSource property, it would require to derive from ListView.

Comment: Not it doesn't. When you set your attached property, if View is null, then wait for the View to be set and return. You can attach to the View change "event" with DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty() / AddValueChanged().